# Confused by the comment "This is valid since $f(t)=\cos^3(t)$ is a continuous function."

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

I'm learning calculus and have encountered the following example in my textbook:

> Find $F'(x)$ if $F(x)=\int_1^x \cos^3(t) \,dt$.
>
> The solution is:
>
> $F'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_1^x \cos^3(t)\, dt\right)=\cos^3(x)$. **This is valid
>   since $f(t)=\cos^3(t)$ is a continuous function.**

I think I understand what is going on (they apply the fundamental theorem of calculus). But I'm confused about the comment they added at the end: "This is valid since...". What part does "**this**" refer to? Why does it have to be continuous? Can you give me any example when the thing that "this" refers to would be invalid (because the function was not continuous), so I can understand the problem better?

Comment: I think it's just saying that fundamental theorem of calculus applies to $cos^3(t)$ since that is a continuous function. e.g. Fundamental Theorem doesn't apply to intervals where the function is not continuous (even if it's integrable).

Answer (score 2):

The point is that it **need not be true** that $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t) \, dt$ has the derivative $F'(x)=f(x)$, unless $f$ is continuous at the point $x$.

For example, if
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases} 0,& x<0, \\ 1,& x \ge 0, \end{cases}
$$
then
$$
F(x)=\int_0^x f(t) \, dt
=\begin{cases} 0,& x<0, \\ x,& x \ge 0, \end{cases}
$$
which isn't differentiable at the point $x=0$ (where $f$ is discontinuous),
since the right-hand derivative $F'_+(0)=1$ differs from the left-hand derivative ${F}'_-(0)=0$.

It *is* true that $F'(x)=f(x)$ for $x \neq 0$, though.

Answer (score 0):

The continuity is an assumption for the fundamental theorem of calculus which states : **Each continuous function on an open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}$ admits an anti-derivative.** (Which is given by the integral.) You can for exemple check that the function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = 1$ if $x>0$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x\leq 0$ has no anti-derivative.

Comment: But for example $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ has an anti-derivative $F(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2}$ but $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is not continuous as it has an asymptote at $x=0$.

Comment: You must precise where your function is defined. In your exemple, $\Omega = \mathbb{R}\backslash \{0\}$ and $f$ is continuous in $\Omega.$

Comment: But of course the theorem only states that continuity implies anti-derivative, not the converse. It is possible to find a non-continuous function which admits an anti-derivative.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)$ is integrable, then $\int_1^x f(t)dt$ is continuous.

If $f(x)$ is continuous, then $\int_1^x f(t)dt$ is differentiable and the derivative of $\int_1^x f(t)dt$ is $f(x)$.

The word "this" refers to the fact that the derivative exists and (roughly speaking) "can be evaluated by removing the integral sign a renaming the variable". Without continuity you cannot evaluate the derivative in this way. The example has been given by C. Dubussy in his answer.